# condition using eval output "-" if eval value has 0.00 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

i want to display - in a column in datalist if the eval value is 0.00

```
<td style="width:80px; text-align:center"><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Withdraw", "{0:n}").ToString() == "0.00" ? "-": Eval("Withdraw") %>' ID="some" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
```

if i use like above the following error is shown "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control".

i tried like this

```
<td style="width:80px; text-align:center"><% if (!Eval("Withdraw", "{0:n}").Contains("0.00"))  {  Eval("Withdraw", "{0:n}");  } else  {%> - <%} %> </td>
```

i dont get proper output

i now i can use code behind i can take the label id from datalist and display with condition but i want to make it simple with some condition in frontend itself please help

Comment: Could you add the full code for the table? I believe that the problem might be there

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
<table style="padding:2% ;">
<tr  >
<td style="width:70px"><%# Eval("Dedate","{0:d}")%> </td>
<td style="width:155px; text-align:center"> <%# Eval("Place")%> </td>
<td style="width:80px; text-align:center"><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Withdraw", "{0:n}").ToString() == "0.00" ? "-": Eval("Withdraw") %>' ID="some" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
<td style="width:80px; text-align:center"><%# Eval("Deposit", "{0:n}")%> </td>
<td style="width:80px; text-align:center"><%# Eval("Balance", "{0:n}")%> </td>  
</tr>

</table>
</ItemTemplate>

Comment: i got thank you   <td style="width:80px; text-align:center"><asp:label text='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Withdraw").ToString()) %>' id="some" runat="server"></asp:label></td>  
public string GetStatus(string status){ switch (status)   { case "0.00":  return "-"; break;default: return status; break; }

            
        }